How do I create a custom button class in tkinter?
I want to create a custom class for the tkinter button class. However when I run my code the button doesn't appear on my window. The programme doesn't throw any errors either. Running on Mac on python 3.9.
import tkinter, sys
from tkinter import *

class CustomButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, button_text):
        Button.__init__(self, master = parent)
        self.text = button_text

class Screen(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Button Test")
        self.geometry("300x300")
        self.new_button = CustomButton(self, "Button One")
        self.new_button.pack()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Screen()
    app.mainloop()

I tried positioning the button using .pack() and .grid() but neither yielded any results.

Did you get a button without using class? If not, it is the issue on your Python installatioin.  Try reinstalling Python from python.org.  Note also that setting the attribute .text does not set the text of the button.  You need to set the text option in Button.__init__(...).

@acw1668 Setting the text in the Button.init() worked. Thanks.

For Mac.
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

